# div overlaying update panel in asp.net page

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net, ajax

I have some problem with displaying elements on my ASP.NET site. I am trying to create a simple chat application. If you look, at the `.aspx` code below, you will see that I have a section inside my `UpdatePanel`. This section contains of four divs. For now, it works almost okay by me. By almost I mean, that the last `<div>` shouldn't really be into `UpdatePanel` because it makes the `<asp:TextBox>` to be refreshed every post back and I need to use some javascript to move cursor to the end of it. But it is annoying and doesn't work as I would like to:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server" defaultbutton="btnSend" defaultfocus="tBox">
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
        <asp:Timer runat="server" ID="updateTimer" OnTick="updateTimer_Tick" Interval="3000"></asp:Timer>
        <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
            <Triggers>
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="updateTimer"/>
            </Triggers>
            <ContentTemplate>
                <section>
                    <div style="background-color:plum;text-align:center;" runat="server">    
                        <asp:Label ID="lblWelcome" runat="server" Text="Czat rodzinny :)"></asp:Label>
                    </div>
                    <div id="one" style="overflow-y:scroll;">
                        <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="litMessages"></asp:Literal>
                    </div>
                    <div id="two" style="overflow-y:scroll";>
                        <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="litUsers"></asp:Literal>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="tBox" Width="70%"></asp:TextBox>
                        <ajaxToolkit:FilteredTextBoxExtender runat="server" FilterType="Custom" InvalidChars="><" FilterMode="InvalidChars" TargetControlID="tBox"/>
                        <asp:Button runat="server" Text="Wyślij" Width="5%" ID="btnSend" OnClick="btnSend_Click"/>
                        <asp:Label runat="server" Width="4%">Kolor:</asp:Label>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlColors" runat="server"  Width="13%" ></asp:DropDownList>
                        <asp:Button runat="server" Text="Wyloguj" Width="6%" />
                    </div>                              
                </section>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </form>
```

So, I wanted to move this `<div> to be after`UpdatePanel`. But when I do so, it displays like on the image below:
[image]

So, as you can see, it doesn't display below, but it's overlaying the `<section>` and I don't know why. Below is th CSS:

```
        section{
            width: 100%;
            height: 80vh;
            background: aqua;     
            display:table;   
        }

        div#one {
        width: 80%;
        height: 100%;
        background-color:white;
        border-style:solid;
        border-width:5px;
        border-color:brown;
        float: left;
        box-sizing:border-box;
        }

        div#two {
        width: 20%;
        height: 100%;
        background-color:white;
        border-style:solid;
        border-width:5px;
        border-color:brown;
        float: left;
        box-sizing:border-box;
        }

        #tBox{
            vertical-align:bottom;
        }

        .text, .image, .block {display:table-cell;}
         div, img { vertical-align:middle;}
```

What is it that I am doing wrong? Any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: If you want to move the last div outside of the UpdatePanel, shouldn't the section contain the UpdatePanel + the last div?

Comment: @ConnorsFan I've tried that, but it gives exactly the same result.

Comment: The UpdatePanel itself must be output as a div (you can check the HTML output). So, would you have to set some CSS attributes to it? Maybe some of the same attributes that are applied to "two"...

Comment: @ConnorsFan Your comment directed me towards the solution. Altough, there weren't any other CSS that I've posted, I needed to change `RenderMode` for the `UpdatePanel` to inline. That makes it `<span>` as an output and works great for me. Thanks:)

Comment: I'm glad that it helped! :-)